# Android Developer quotation

Tags: android

I write a projectwork for university. I developed an Androidapp. Inside my documentation for that work I have quotations from Android Developer Site (http://developer.android.com/index.html). Now I don't understand who publishs these informations. Is it Google, is it AOSP? And I can't find out when it is released.

For Example if I used text from this site as a quotation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Who publish it and when?

Hope somebody can help me. I looked already at http://developer.android.com/legal.html . But its a little bit confusing.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/license.html: "The documentation content on this site is made available to you as part of the Android Open Source Project. This documentation, including any code shown in it, is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license, the preferred license for all parts of the of the Android Open Source Project."

Comment: Yep thanks you're right. And have you ever find a date on site?